# Django Will Not Open Up Static File Image, Django 3

Tags: python, html, django

So I have been trying to figure out why the image will not show and I have watched and read numerous things, but i still can't find anything. This is my first question on here. Thanks for helping out

**HTML**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Nikhil's Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>
test
<img scr="{% static 'static/homepage/wpap.jpg' %}" alt="why is it not working">
<img scr="{% static 'static/homepage/download.jpg' %}" alt="why is it not working">

</body>

</html>
```

**url.py of my website (not app url)**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('homepage.urls'))
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

**How my files are arranged**
[img of file organization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcn5r.jpg)

Comment: also i am using django 3.0.1, not 3 if that makes a difference

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It would need to change from this:

```
<img scr="{% static 'static/homepage/wpap.jpg' %}" alt="why is it not working">
```

To this:

```
<img src="{% static 'static/homepage/wpap.jpg' %}" alt="why is it not working">
```

The "scr" would change to "src"

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    {% static 'homepage/wpap.jpg' %}
```

Instead of

```
    {% static 'static/homepage/wpap.jpg' %}
```

Comment: nope, still the same. thank you for trying to help.